Solving Laplace equation
I have the Boundary value problem below using the method of Separation of Variables
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0, \ x\in[0,2\pi], \ y\in[0,2\pi]$$
$$u(x,0)=\cos x, \ x\in[0,2\pi]$$
$$u(x,2\pi)=1,\ x\in[0,2\pi]$$
$$u(0,y)=u(2\pi,y)=1,\ y\in [0,2\pi]$$
I don't know how to solve this problem, can someone help me? so let's look at two problems I do know how to solve. The first will be $\nabla^2U=0$, $U_x(0,y)=U_x(L,y)=U(x,L)=0$, and $U_y(x,0)=1-\cos\frac{\pi x}L$. We can solve by separation of variables with $U(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, so $YX^{\prime\prime}+XY^{\prime\prime}=0$ and
$$\frac1XX^{\prime\prime}=-\frac1YY^{\prime\prime}=-\lambda$$
Where $\lambda$ is the separation constant. If $\lambda<0$, then $X=c_1\cosh\sqrt{-\lambda}x+c_2\sinh\sqrt{-\lambda}x$. At $x=0$, $X^{\prime}(0)=0=c_2\sqrt{-\lambda}$, so $c_2=0$ and at $x=L$, $X^{\prime}(L)=c_1\sqrt{-\lambda}\sinh(\sqrt{-\lambda}L)=0$, so also $c_1=0$, the trivial solution.
If $\lambda=0$, then $X=c_1+c_2x$. At $x=0$, $X^{\prime}(0)=0=c_2$, so $X_0(x)=1$ is a solution that also satisfies $X^{\prime}(L)=0$. Then $Y^{\prime\prime}=0$ so $Y(y)=c_3+c_4(L-y)$, and $Y(L)=0=c_3$ so $Y_0(y)=L-y$
If $\lambda>0$, then $X=c_1\cos\sqrt{\lambda}x+c_2\sin\sqrt{\lambda}x$. At $x=0$, $X^{\prime}(0)=c_2\sqrt{\lambda}=0$, so $c_2=0$, and at $x=L$, $X^{\prime}(L)=-c_1\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\sqrt{\lambda}L=0=\sin n\pi$, so $\lambda_n=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}$ and $X_n(x)=\cos\frac{n\pi x}L$. Then $Y^{\prime\prime}(y)=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L^2}Y$ with solution $Y=c_3\cosh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L+c_4\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L$. At $y=L$, $Y(L)=0=c_3$ so $Y_n(y)=\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L$. Then we have
$$U(x,y)=a_0(L-y)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}L\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L$$
And
$$U_y(x,0)=1-\cos\frac{\pi x}L=-a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}-\frac{n\pi}La_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}L\cosh n\pi$$
We could use orthogonality of the eigenfunctions to determine the coefficients $a_n$, but by inspection $a_0=-1$, $a_1=\frac L{\pi\cosh\pi}$ and all other $a_n=0$, so
$$U_1(x,y)=y-L+\frac L{\pi\cosh\pi}\cos\frac{n\pi x}L\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L$$
The other problem I know how to solve is $\nabla^2U=0$, $U_x(0,y)=U(x,L)=U_y(x,0)=0$, and $U_x(L,y)=\cos\frac{\pi y}{2L}$. Again $U(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, so $YX^{\prime\prime}+XY^{\prime\prime}=0$ and
$$\frac1XX^{\prime\prime}=-\frac1YY^{\prime\prime}=\lambda$$
If $\lambda<0$, then $Y=c_1\cosh\sqrt{-\lambda}y+c_2\sinh\sqrt{-\lambda}y$. At $y=0$, $Y^{\prime}(0)=0=c_2\sqrt{-\lambda}$ so $c_2=0$. At $y=L$, $Y(L)=0=c_1\cosh\sqrt{-\lambda}L$, so we only get the trivial solution.
If $\lambda=0$, then $Y=c_1+c_2y$. At $y=0$, $Y^{\prime}(0)=0=c_2$ and at $y=L$, $Y(L)=0=c_1$, i.e. only the trivial solution.
If $\lambda>0$, then $Y=c_1\cos\sqrt{\lambda}y+c_2\sin\sqrt{\lambda}y$. At $y=0$, $Y^{\prime}(0)=0=\sqrt{\lambda}c_2$. At $y=L$, $Y(L)=0=c_1\cos\sqrt{\lambda}L=\cos\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$, so $\lambda_n=\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)^2\pi^2}{L^2}$ and $Y_n=\cos\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi y}L$. Then $X^{\prime\prime}=\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi^2}{L^2}X$ with solution $X=c_3\cosh\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x}L+c_4\sinh\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x}L$. At $x=0$, $X^{\prime}(0)=0=c_4\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi}L$, so $c_4=0$, and $X_n(x)=\cosh\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x}L$. So this time
$$U(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n\cos\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi y}L\cosh\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi x}L$$
And
$$U_x(L,y)=\cos\frac{\pi y}{2L}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi}Lb_n\cos\frac{\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi y}L\sinh\left(n+\frac12\right)\pi$$
As before we find by inspection that $b_0=\frac{2L}{\pi\sinh\frac{\pi}2}$ and all other $b_n=0$, so the solution to this problem is
$$U_2(x,y)=\frac{2L}{\pi\sinh\frac{\pi}2}\cos\frac{\pi y}{2L}\cosh\frac{\pi x}{2L}$$
We can find the solution to the original problem by superposition
$$\begin{align}U(x,y)&=U_1(x,y)+U_2(x,y)\\
&=y-L+\frac L{\pi\cosh\pi}\cos\frac{n\pi x}L\sinh\frac{n\pi(L-y)}L+\frac{2L}{\pi\sinh\frac{\pi}2}\cos\frac{\pi y}{2L}\cosh\frac{\pi x}{2L}\end{align}$$

any solution please?

In order to use the method of separation of variables, we need homogeneous boundary conditions. Defining $v:=u-1$, we can rewrite the problem as
\begin{align}
v_{xx}+v_{yy}&=0, \tag{1} \\
v(x,0)&=\cos x - 1, \tag{2} \\
v(x,2\pi)&= 0, \tag{3} \\
v(0,y)&= 0, \tag{4} \\
v(2\pi,y)&= 0. \tag{5}
\end{align}
Now, three of the four boundary conditions are homogeneous.
Substituting $v(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ in $(1)$, we get
$$
X''(x)Y(y)+X(x)Y''(y)=0 \implies \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}+\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=0
$$
$$
\implies \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=\lambda
\implies\begin{cases}
X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0, \\
Y''(y)-\lambda Y(y)=0. 
\end{cases} \tag{6}
$$
Because the boundary conditions $(3)$-$(5)$ are homogeneous, we may subject the solutions to $(6)$ to the boundary conditions
\begin{align}
X(0)&=0, \tag{7} \\
X(2\pi)&=0, \tag{8} \\
Y(2\pi)&=0. \tag{9}
\end{align}
The nontrivial solutions to $X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0$ satisfying $(7)$ and $(8)$ are
$$
X_n(x)=A_n\sin\left(\sqrt{\lambda_n}x\right), \qquad \lambda_n=\frac{n^2}{4}\qquad(n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}). \tag{10}
$$
The corresponding solutions to $Y''(y)-\lambda_nY(x)=0$ satisfying $(9)$ are
$$
Y_n(x)=B_n\sinh\left(\sqrt{\lambda_n}(2\pi-y)\right). \tag{11}
$$
Therefore, the general solution to $(1)$ satisfying $(3)$-$(5)$ is
$$
v(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_nX_n(x)Y_n(y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n
\sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)\sinh\left(\frac{n}{2}(2\pi-y)\right). \tag{12}
$$
To determine the coefficients $C_n$, we use the boundary condition $(2)$:
$$
v(x,0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n\sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)\sinh(n\pi)
=\cos x - 1 
$$
$$
\implies C_n\sinh(n\pi)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos x - 1)\sin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)dx. \tag{13}
$$
(I leave for you the computation of the integral.)
The final result is $u(x,y)=v(x,y)+1$, where $v$ is given by $(12)$ and $(13)$.
